Why these diagonal lines are appears?

I made some models in blender and imported to unity. Then diagonal lines show up in scene.

When i added other models over it, lines still there...
I checked all normals and there is no problem but I still can't figure out why that is happening?

its most likely normals or texture, there isnt a lot more that usually causes that

Thats shadow acne! Check out this answer for a fix.

Does this answer your question? Is there anyway to fix this? Unity materials with diagonal lines

Thank you both, this is definitely the cause of the problem, but no matter how I play with bias, it doesn't fix it completely. Should I update model with a technic or something?

Changing cast shadow to two sided in mesh renderer helped me.
Source:
https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/Manual/ShadowOverview.html
